# Monoid to Trim & Add Whitespace Between Words

Tags: scala

How is my attempt at implementing [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/)'s below exercise?

```
// EXERCISE 5: Write a monoid instance for that String inserts spaces
// between words unless there already is one, and trims spaces off the ends of the
// result.
def trimMonoid = new Monoid[String] {
    def op(a1: String, a2: String) = a1.trim + " " + a2.trim
    val zero = ""
}
```

Is this the proper way to test the monoid? Here's the function signature, but I'm not sure how to implement with what I have: `def trimMonoid(s: String): Monoid[String]`.

```
object MonoidTesting {
def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val words = List("Hic", "Est", "Barbarus")

    val res = trimMonoid.op( ("Hic"), (trimMonoid.op("est ", "chorda ")) )
    println("res : " + res)
    assert(res == "Hic est chorda")

    println("success")
  }
}
```

Comment: Just in case you missed it, the authors have a [github repository](https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala) with hints and solutions for all the exercises.

Answer (score 1):

One of the use cases of `Monoid` is in `fold`. I guess in Scala you have foldLeft and foldRight that you can use to test it on the list of string

```
val res = words.foldLeft(trimMonoid.zero)(trimMonoid.op _)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your `trimMonoid` does correctly what the exercise asks for, but anyways if its for testing then you could test it better this way:

```
scala> val xs = List("hey","hi","hello")
xs: List[String] = List(hey, hi, hello)

scala> xs.foldLeft(trimMonoid.zero)((x,y)=> trimMonoid.op(x,y))
res2: String = hey hi hello
```